# how to synchronized Checkbuttons in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to deselect the Var2 Checkbutton, if Var1 Checkbutton is selected and vice versa. Following code works only one way, because if Var1 is already selected, `var1.get()` is true and Var2 is set to 0. Is there a simple way of linking two or more Checkbuttons?

```
import tkinter as tk
 

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('My Window')
window.geometry('200x200')
 
l = tk.Label(window, bg='white', width=20, text='empty')
l.pack()
 
def change_status():
    if var1.get():
        var2.set(0)
    elif var2.get():
        var1.set(0)

 
var1 = tk.IntVar()
var2 = tk.IntVar()
c1 = tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Var1',variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=change_status)
c1.pack()
c2 = tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Var2',variable=var2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=change_status)
c2.pack()
 
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why don't you use one ```var1``` for both check button

Comment: It sounds like you want radiobuttons instead of checkbuttons. Checkbuttons are designed to be independent, radiobuttons are designed to present an exclusive choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass some argument to that function so it knows which `Checkbutton` was pressed or create two functions and pass fun1 and fun2 to the command parameter of checkbutton1 and checkbutton2 respectively.

example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
 
window = tk.Tk()

def change_status(btn):

    if btn:
        c1.deselect()

    else:
        c2.deselect()

    
var1 = tk.IntVar()
var2 = tk.IntVar()
c1 = tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Var1',variable=var1, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=lambda: change_status(0))
c1.pack()
c2 = tk.Checkbutton(window, text='Var2',variable=var2, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=lambda: change_status(1))
c2.pack()
 
window.mainloop()
```

But I believe that you should be using `Radiobutton` for this purpose

example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()


var1 = tk.IntVar()

c1 = tk.Radiobutton(window, text='Var1',variable=var1, value=0)
c1.pack()
c2 = tk.Radiobutton(window, text='Var2',variable=var1, value=1)
c2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```